# Unable to push data with more than 50MB

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, push

I'm trying to push the code retrieved from my prod sandbox into a scratch org. After converting the code i tried to push it. The problem is that my code has ~ 200MB (is a monolithic app) and i can not push code that has more than ~50MB, right?
I've tried to zip the code but i believe that pushing a zip file is not allowed...
Anyone has gone through a similar problem? 
Any ideas?

Comment: How much of those are static resources with images which does not change that often?

Comment: The code has been cleaned up. Before that it had ~ 300MB. Even if we could delete some more, it would never be less than 50MB. There's no other way to surpass this size limit?